# Are DFAs unique?

Tags: finite-automata

For a given regular is expression, once we construct a deterministic finite automaton: is that automaton unique for that expression? In a sense, that no other DFA (different number of vertices or transitions) can be constructed from that same regular expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For every regular language there are *infinitely many* DFAs accepting the language. You can always add dummy states not reachable from the initial state, for example.

However, there is a unique DFA which has the minimum number of states, called the *minimal automaton* (or some such name). This is part of [Myhill–Nerode theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: (Unique up to isomorphism.)

Comment: How to make a state which is unreachable? Can a DFA be disconnected?

Comment: @Gyanshu There is absolutely no requirement in the definition of DFA that its graph be connected.